# 'Georgetown' in UTC-3:00 - where is it exactly?

Tags: timezone

I am trying to verify a timezone list from:
https://github.com/tamaspap/timezones

And I have noticed that there is a 'Georgetown' in UTC-3:00. But I am wondering where is the location of this 'Georgetown' exactly? I did searched on the Internet, but don't see any Georgetown in UTC-3:00?

Comment: Hmm. Wikipedia has UTC -4:00.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgetown,_Guyana

Comment: There is a Georgetown in PEI Canada

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case is a perfect example of why one has to be very careful with building custom lists of time zones.  The fact is, there are [many cities named GeorgeTown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgetown).

In particular, there are two different cities being confused here.

- [Georgetown, Guyana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgetown,_Guyana) - the capital city of that country

  - IANA time zone ID: `America/Guyana`
  - Time Zone Offset: UTC-4  (no DST)
- Georgetown, Córdoba, Argentina - a suburb of the city of [Córdoba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3rdoba,_Argentina)

  - IANA time zone ID: `America/Argentina/Cordoba`
  - Time Zone Offset: UTC-3  (no DST)

It appears that the author of that time zone list was looking at other various time zone lists that have an entry for Georgetown.  Perhaps it was one of these (or based on them):

- The Windows operating system, which has an entry: `Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan`
- Rails, whose [ActiveSupport:TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) list contains an entry for `Georgetown`

However, in both cases, the Georgetown being referred to is the one in Guyana, and the author of the project you mentioned incorrectly mapped it to Argentina, as seen [in their source code](https://github.com/tamaspap/timezones/blob/da73aa2e0d9bb8fc7858ba8d31536da24792258b/php/timezone_list.php#L32):

```
'(UTC-03:00) Georgetown' => 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',
```

They also chose the wrong sub-region within Argentina, but both are on UTC-3.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like someone should file an issue.

Comment: Yeah, I just fired an issue on GitHub.